# I Can't get the most simple knockout.js sample to work?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have tried this code but this not working properly. my code is below

```
<link href="~/Content/knocktest.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ViewModel = function (first, last) {

                this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
                this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

                this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {                  

                    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
                }, this);
            };
            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
        });
    </script>
```

my html code below

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
```

Comment: Your example code works fine.  Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to attach jQuery?

Comment: hello  @f_martinez , knockout-2.3.0.js  which is still there i have check it

Comment: @JosephGabriel, i cant get any error there

Comment: Knockout is not enough. You are using `$` in your code, that definitely refers to jQuery too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no errors in your code, so really the only thing that you are missing is your reference to the jQuery library since you are using;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // rest of your code here
});
```

If you don't include jQuery then you can just remove the `$(document).ready()` code, and make sure that your JavaScript is after all of your html elements within the body.

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>
<span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js"> </script>
<script>

    var ViewModel = function (first, last) {

        this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
        this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

        this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        }, this);

    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));

</script>
```

Please check out this [demo of your code at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iSAvoTA/1/edit?html,output)